# Provisioning profile in AS3?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

When the work was published this message appear?
What meaning?
How to solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deploy this (whether to the store or internally at your company), you need to add a provisioning profile so your app will run on other devices.  Do you have an Apple Developer Account?

If so, [here is a tutorial direct from Adobe on how to get and use the files you need](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-33e1d8031250a54a821-7fff.html).

And there's [a whole selection of them found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/index.html).